# jQuery - Splice after first non-alpha-numerical?

Tags: jquery, regex, splice

I am trying to incorporate a `splice` such that it tests for 2 things:

1. Characters cannot be longer than 20, removes the rest
2. It stops at the first non-alpha-numerical, removes the rest ?

How would I go about doing this ? i.e. for example

`var string = 'Special Place Co. (123 ABC)'`

So this would return

'Special Place Co' [found '.' and removed spliced after]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that will work for you:

```
var string = 'Special Place Co. (123 ABC)';


if (string.length > 20) {
  string = string.substr(0,20);   
}

string = string.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)(.*)/,'{$1}');


console.log(string);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U5ZtU/

Comment: Change `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` to [a-zA-Z0-9\- ]

Comment: p.s - the regex might be better like [\w\s\-] :)